# Can you nest "Fn::FindInMap" inside "Fn::Sub"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm doing this:

```
{"Fn::Join": [":", [
    "arn:aws:sns",
    { "Ref": "AWS::Region"},
    { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},
    {"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "config", "mytopic", { "Ref" : "deployment" } ] }
]]
```

But I would prefer to use SUB like this but it's not valid JSON:

```
{"Fn::Sub" : "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "config", "mytopic", { "Ref" : "deployment" } ] }"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `Fn::FindInMap` directly from the `Fn::Sub` template. [Only a limited number of expressions work OOTB.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c26c24c59b7)

Instead you can pass additional variables to `Fn::Sub`. For example:

```
      DefinitionString: !Sub 
        - |-
          {
             "Comment":"Extract metadata and anonymize the videoclip",
             "StartAt":"ExtractMetadataAndAnonymize",
             "States":{
                "ExtractMetadataAndAnonymize":{
                   "Type":"Parallel",
                   "Next":"LogResult",
                   "Branches":[
                      {
                         "StartAt":"AlarmIfVideoverarbeitungClusterIsEmpty",
                         "States":{
                            "AlarmIfVideoverarbeitungClusterIsEmpty":{
                               "Type":"Task",
                               "Resource":"${EmptyVideoverarbeitungClusterAlarmFunction_Arn}",
                               ....
                }
             }
          }
        - EmptyVideoverarbeitungClusterAlarmFunction_Arn: !ImportValue 
            'Fn::Sub': 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-videoverarbeitung-cluster-EmptyVideoverarbeitungClusterAlarmFunction-Arn'
```

Here, I calculate some value and pass it as `EmptyVideoverarbeitungClusterAlarmFunction_Arn` variable to `Sub`.

Comment: Im confused about your example. I understand that what I want to do isnt supported. but I dont understand "I calculate some value..." and how you example would help me use my map of values- which is a map of settings to envs (dev, prod, etc). my only issue with Join is the verbosity and clunkiness of its syntax

Comment: @red888 My example shows how you can calculate and pass some value as a variable to `Sub` and use it in `Sub`s template. So if you replace the `EmptyVideoverarbeitungClusterAlarmFunction_Arn` in my example with, say `MyTopic` and calculate it as you want with `Fn::FindInMap`, you'll be able to use `${MyTopic}` in your `Sub` template.

Comment: @red888 No. Why?